# jQuery Website Header Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I moved around some divs in my HTML to neaten up the code a little, but I didn't back up the old file and saved it directly into my FTP, overwriting the old file.

Now when you scroll down past 150px it makes you go to the top of the page (Only on bigger screens). I'm not quite sure how to fix or what I've done wrong, but any help would be great!

HTML (Without main content to cut down size):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title>ItzJavaCraft | ModPE Members</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/tachyons@4.0.0-beta.22/css/tachyons.min.css">

    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Actor' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="/assets/images/icon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png">

    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header-fixed">
      <div class="header-limiter">
        <h1><a href="http://itzjavacraft.tk">ItzJavaCraft</a></h1>
        <nav>
          <a href="http://itzjavacraft.tk" class="selected">Home</a>
          <a href="http://itzjavacraft.tk/blog">Blog</a>
          <a href="http://itzjavacraft.tk/tutorials">Tutorials</a>
          <a href="http://itzjavacraft.tk/news">News</a>
          <a href="http://itzjavacraft.tk/contact">Contact</a>
          <a href="http://itzjavacraft.tk/about">About</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="header-fixed-placeholder">
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="main">
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer-distributed">
      <div class="footer-left">
        <h3>ItzJavaCraft</h3>
        <p class="footer-links">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
            »
          <a href="#">Blog</a>
            »
          <a href="#">Pricing</a>
            »
          <a href="#">About</a>
            »
          <a href="#">Faq</a>
            »
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </p>
        <p class="footer-company-name">Copyright © 2016 <b>ItzJavaCraft</b>, All Rights Reserved</p>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-center">
        <div>
          <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
          <p><a href="mailto:itzjavacraft@gmail.com">itzjavacraft@gmail.com</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-right">
        <p class="footer-company-about"><span>Oh, hello there...</span>My name is Java. No, not the programming language! Well, this is awkward. Not much else to be said... uhm... enjoy your stay, I guess!</p>
        <div class="footer-icons">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
          <a href="http://twitter.com/itzjavacraft"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
          <a href="http://instagram.com/itzjavacraft"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/3/100627374146825887109" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <div class="menu">
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var showHeaderAt = 150;
          var win = $(window),
              body = $("body");
          if(win.width() > 600){
            win.on("scroll", function(e){
              if(win.scrollTop() > showHeaderAt) {
                body.addClass("fixed");
              }
              else {
                body.removeClass("fixed");
              }
            });
          }
        });
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var showHeaderAt = 150;
  var win = $(window),
      body = $("body");
  if(win.width() > 600){
    win.on("scroll", function(e){
      if(win.scrollTop() > showHeaderAt) {
        body.addClass("fixed");
      }
      else {
        body.removeClass("fixed");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Note: It was working just fine before I moved around the divs.

A live version of the site can be found [here](http://itzjavacraft.tk/tutorials/modpe/global/members.html) and a JSFiddle, fiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ItzJavaCraft/ycm9cuLg/).

Comment: Your live version isn't so live right now.

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks Yes, it is.

Comment: honestly - that link opens up completely white page.

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks http://itzjavacraft.tk/tutorials/modpe/global/members.html

Comment: check [my screenshot](http://imgur.com/FLtelcq)

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks That's strange. It is working for me on my devices, phone, computer, et cetera. I've also cleared my cache but it still loads.

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks The JSFiddle is working. People can use that if they can't load the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it has to do with the class name of "fixed". Did you introduce any new stylesheets? I tried changing the rules and add/removeClass to "fixed1" and it now works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var showHeaderAt = 150;
  var win = $(window),
    body = $("body");

  if (win.width() > 600) {
    win.scrollTop();
    var test = 0;
    console.log("Greater than 600. win.scrollTop: ", test);

    win.on("scroll", function(e) {
      var st = $(window).scrollTop();
      console.log("ST: ", st);

      if (st > showHeaderAt) {
        body.addClass("fixed1");
      } else {
        body.removeClass("fixed1");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
/* Toolkit */

hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
img.center-align {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.text-align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE/Edge */
  user-select: none;
  /* non-prefixed version, currently not supported by any browser */
}
.word-wrap {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* IE 5.5-7 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  /* Firefox 1.0-2.0 */
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* current browsers */
}
/* Links */

a:link {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 75%;
}
a:visited {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 75%;
}
a:hover {
  color: #9700bd;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 75%;
}
a:active {
  color: #9700bd;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 75%;
}
/* Header */

.header-fixed {
  background-color: #292c2f;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  height: 80px;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: -100px;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}
.header-fixed .header-limiter {
  max-width: 1200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.header-fixed-placeholder {
  height: 80px;
  display: none;
}
.header-fixed .header-limiter h1 {
  float: left;
  font: normal 28px Cookie, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}
.header-fixed .header-limiter h1 span {
  color: #5383d3;
}
.header-fixed .header-limiter a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.header-fixed .header-limiter nav {
  font: 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
  float: right;
}
.header-fixed .header-limiter nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.header-fixed .header-limiter nav a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.header-fixed .header-limiter nav a.selected {
  color: #608bd2;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
body.fixed1 .header-fixed {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
body.fixed1 .header-fixed-placeholder {
  display: block;
}
body.fixed1 .header-fixed .header-limiter h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
body.fixed1 .header-fixed .header-limiter nav {
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .header-fixed {
    padding: 20px 0;
    height: 75px;
  }
  .header-fixed .header-limiter h1 {
    float: none;
    margin: -8px 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1;
  }
  .header-fixed .header-limiter nav {
    line-height: 1;
    float: none;
  }
  .header-fixed .header-limiter nav a {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  body.fixed1 .header-fixed {
    display: none;
  }
}
/* ModPE API CSS */

.name {
  background-color: #F5FFE8;
  color: #00209D;
}
table.modpe {
  border: 0;
  width: 75%;
  font-family: monospace;
}
th.modpe {
  text-align: left;
  width: 16.66666667%;
}
td.modpe {
  width: 16.66666667%;
}
div.code-box {
  border-left: 5px solid #8026C0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
div.code-box-border {
  border: 2px solid #E8E8E8;
  background: #E8E8E8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #ABABAB;
  padding: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
}
td.name {
  color: #00DAFF;
}
h4.code-example-heading {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
pre.no-border {
  border: none !important;
}
hr.modpe {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
/* Footer */

.footer-distributed {
  background-color: #292c2f;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font: bold 16px sans-serif;
  padding: 55px 50px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
.footer-distributed .footer-left,
.footer-distributed .footer-center,
.footer-distributed .footer-right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.footer-distributed .footer-left {
  width: 40%;
}
.footer-distributed h3 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font: normal 36px'Cookie', cursive;
  margin: 0;
}
.footer-distributed h3 span {
  color: #5383d3;
}
.footer-distributed .footer-links {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 20px 0 12px;
  padding: 0;
}
.footer-distributed .footer-links a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
.footer-distributed .footer-company-name {
  color: #8f9296;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}
.footer-distributed .footer-center {
  width: 35%;
}
.footer-distributed .footer-center i {
  background-color: #33383b;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 42px;
  margin: 10px 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.footer-distributed .footer-center i.fa-envelope {
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 38px;
}
.footer-distributed .footer-center p {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}
.footer-distributed .footer-center p span {
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 2;
}
.footer-distributed .footer-center p a {
  color: #5383d3;
  text-decoration: none;
  ;
}
.footer-distributed .footer-right {
  width: 20%;
}
.footer-distributed .footer-company-about {
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #92999f;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}
.footer-distributed .footer-company-about span {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.footer-distributed .footer-icons {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.footer-distributed .footer-icons a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #33383b;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
@media (max-width: 880px) {
  .footer-distributed {
    font: bold 14px sans-serif;
  }
  .footer-distributed .footer-left,
  .footer-distributed .footer-center,
  .footer-distributed .footer-right {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .footer-distributed .footer-center i {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
/* Other */

body {
  margin: 0px;
}
div.main {} div.wrap {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
#comments {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/assets/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/tachyons@4.0.0-beta.22/css/tachyons.min.css">

  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Actor' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="/assets/images/icon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png">

  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <header class="header-fixed">
      <div class="header-limiter">
        <h1><a href="http://itzjavacraft.tk">ItzJavaCraft</a></h1>
        <nav>
          <a href="http://itzjavacraft.tk" class="selected">Home</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
<div class="header-fixed-placeholder"></div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div style="height:1000px;" class="main">
MAIN
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer-distributed">
  <div class="footer-left">
    <h3>ItzJavaCraft</h3>
    <p class="footer-links">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
        »
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
        »
      <a href="#">Pricing</a>
        »
      <a href="#">About</a>
        »
      <a href="#">Faq</a>
        »
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </p>
    <p class="footer-company-name">Copyright © 2016 <b>ItzJavaCraft</b>, All Rights Reserved</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-center">
    <div>
      <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
      <p><a href="mailto:itzjavacraft@gmail.com">itzjavacraft@gmail.com</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-right">
    <p class="footer-company-about"><span>Oh, hello there...</span>My name is Java. No, not the programming language! Well, this is awkward. Not much else to be said... uhm... enjoy your stay, I guess!</p>
    <div class="footer-icons">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="http://twitter.com/itzjavacraft"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="http://instagram.com/itzjavacraft"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/3/100627374146825887109" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
    <div class="menu"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I added the [Tachyons](http://tachyons.io) stylesheet. I didn't think about checking the CSS, and I know very little about jQuery so it is hard for me to pick out the problems.

Comment: After inspecting the CSS, it turns out it was the Tachyons stylesheet messing with the page. Thanks for the help! :)